# A library to convert svg to images?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, svg, librsvg

I am looking for a library written either in C or C++ which can convert the svg to image formats.

I came across inkscape which converts svg to images. but to use this I must run inkscape as a process and this not the solution I am after.

I need the library to run on both Windows and Linux as well.

I am after a C or C++ library. If it was with Java I would have used Apache's Batik rasterizer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The canonical library to render SVG is [librsvg](https://live.gnome.org/LibRsvg). You may want to check that out.

Comment: Will that convert svg to raster formats?

Comment: it has a command line tool `rsvg` to do that too, it renders SVG to PNG. The library itself is way more flexible of course.

Comment: Then you also need a jpeg library. You can try http://www.ijg.org/

Answer (score 6):

For image libray, you can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), which is quite popular and it support many types of image.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend leadtools, as they support many vector formats and many programming languages and it can be easily convert vector format to the most known raster format.

As far as I know they support Windows, not sure about Linux.

You can tell by visiting their [website](http://www.leadtools.com/).